# gdb: make a breakpoint on a class function in c++

Tags: c++, gdb

Assume the following class:

```
class a {
   public:
      int getA(int a){
     return 5;
      }
      int getA(int a, int b){
     return 6;
      }
};

int main(){
   a cA;
   std::cout << cA.getA(5) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

in gdb, I can set a `breakpoint` on the `getA` function using:

```
b a::getA
```

But this only sets a `b` on the first function, how do I make a `b` on the second function (without using line number of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more line to your `main()`:

```
std::cout << cA.getA(2,3) << std::endl;
```

Now, repeat your original experiment. Your results will be different, now:

```
(gdb) b a::getA
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40089d: a::getA. (2 locations)
```

"2 locations" is gdb telling you that it now injected breakpoints for both overloaded functions. Stepping through the code will verify this.

If a symbol resolved to multiply-overloaded functions, the `b` command sets a breakpoint at each one.

But because the 2nd overloaded function was an inline function and it was never called in your original code, gcc didn't even compile it, and there was nothing for `gdb` to set a breakpoint at.

Answer (score 0):

`b a::getA(int,int)` should do the trick. Even the one that's already working should be replaceable with `b a::getA(int)`.

Try it yourself [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1sYb7P_E).